# kafka-python: Closing the kafka producer with 0 vs inf secs timeout

Tags: python-2.7, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I am trying to produce the messages to a Kafka topic using kafka-python 2.0.1 using python 2.7 (can't use Python 3 due to some workplace-related limitations)

I created a class as below in a separate and compiled the package and installed in virtual environment:

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer


class KafkaSender(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.producer = self.get_kafka_producer()

    def get_kafka_producer(self):
        return KafkaProducer(
            bootstrap_servers=['locahost:9092'],
            value_serializer=lambda x: json.dumps(x),
            request_timeout_ms=2000,
        )

    def send(self, data):
        self.producer.send("topicname", value=data)
```

My driver code is something like this:

```
from mypackage import KafkaSender

# driver code
data = {"a":"b"}
kafka_sender = KafkaSender()
kafka_sender.send(data)
```

**Scenario 1:**
I run this code, it runs just fine, no errors, but the message is not pushed to the topic. I have confirmed this as offset or lag is not increased in the topic. Also, nothing is getting logged at the consumer end.

**Scenario 2:**
Commented/removed the initialization of Kafka producer from `__init__` method.
I changed the sending line from 
`self.producer.send("topicname", value=data)`  to `self.get_kafka_producer().send("topicname", value=data)` i.e. creating kafka producer not in advance (during class initialization) but right before sending the message to topic. And when I ran the code, it worked perfectly. The message got published to the topic.

My intention using scenario 1 is to create a Kafka producer once and use it multiple times and not to create Kafka producer every time I want to send the messages. This way I might end up creating millions of Kafka producer objects if I need to send millions of messages.

Can you please help me understand why is Kafka producer behaving this way.

NOTE: If I write the Kafka Code and Driver code in same file it works fine. It's not working only when I write the Kafka code in separate package, compile it and import it in my another project.

LOGS: https://www.diffchecker.com/dTtm3u2a

**Update 1: 9th May 2020, 17:20:**
Removed INFO logs from the question description. I enabled the DEBUG level and here is the difference between the debug logs between first scenario and the second scenario

https://www.diffchecker.com/dTtm3u2a

**Update 2: 9th May 2020, 21:28:**
Upon further debugging and looking at python-kafka source code, I was able to deduce that in scenario 1, kafka sender was forced closed while in scenario 2, kafka sender was being closed gracefully.

```
    def initiate_close(self):
        """Start closing the sender (won't complete until all data is sent)."""
        self._running = False
        self._accumulator.close()
        self.wakeup()

    def force_close(self):
        """Closes the sender without sending out any pending messages."""
        self._force_close = True
        self.initiate_close()
```

And this depends on whether kafka producer's `close()` method is called with timeout 0 (forced close of sender) or without timeout (in this case timeout takes value `float('inf')` and graceful close of sender is called.)

Kafka producer's `close()` method is called from `__del__` method which is called at the time of garbage collection. `close(0)` method is being called from method which is registered with `atexit` which is called when [interpreter terminates](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/atexit.html).
Question is why in scenario 1 interpreter is terminating?

Comment: Hey, it's been a long time, but have you found any answer?